# Password reset form not displaying

Tags: django, django-forms

**Update:
Looks like it was a browser issue, now resolved**

When I use the password reset in development it works fine. However in production after the user opens the reset email the password reset form is not displayed however other forms on the site via crispy forms are working fine. Nothing has been changed from dev to production besides the url in the view. The server and dev are running the same version of crispy forms.

I did it based off this [tutorial](https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/django-password-reset) and it seems I have made all the required changes for production

When checking the urls of the email between production and dev i do not see an issue

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/MQ/***hm*-e00d**b30b635b358be1573e********/
https://domain.co/reset/MQ/***ht*-71ff80c**580c6cecc3ffd44********/
```

view that sends the email:

```
def password_reset_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if password_reset_form.is_valid():
            data = password_reset_form.cleaned_data['email']
            associated_users = User.objects.filter(Q(email=data)|Q(username=data))
            if associated_users.exists():
                for user in associated_users:
                    subject = "Password Reset Requested"
                    plaintext = template.loader.get_template('users/password_reset_email.txt')
                    htmltemp = template.loader.get_template('users/password_reset_email.html')
                    c = { 
                    "email":user.email,
                    'domain':'domain.com',
                    'site_name': 'Website',
                    "uid": urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    "user": user,
                    'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
                    'protocol': 'https',
                    }
                    text_content = plaintext.render(c)
                    html_content = htmltemp.render(c)
                    try:
                        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, 'myemail@email.com', [user.email], headers = {'Reply-To': 'myemail@email.com'})
                        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
                        msg.send()
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                    return redirect ("password_reset_done")
    password_reset_form = PasswordResetForm()
    return render(request=request, template_name="users/password_reset.html", context={"password_reset_form":password_reset_form})
```

template that the user resets password (auth_view):

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="loginout-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Reset Password</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="login-register-btn" type="submit">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls:

```
    from users import views as user_views
    path("reset_password/", user_views.password_reset_request, name="password_reset"),
    path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="users/password_reset_sent.html"), name="password_reset_done"),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="users/password_reset_form.html"), name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="users/password_reset_done.html"), name="password_reset_complete"),
```

Update:

If I try and render the form like `{{ form }}` it only renders `None` leading me to believe the context is not being passed and not a crispy issue

Update:

Although I am pretty sure it has nothing to do with it I double checked all my email settings and they look good. I also tried the template from the tutorial and it did the same thing

Update:

Took a look in the docs and found this for the password reset confirm view, It appears I am passing the correct form value of `{{form}}` However When I pass `validlink` to the template it returns false

Update:

I cleared my cache and waited a bit and then the resets were retuning true. I think it was reading false because I had one pending. Tried it on my phone and the form displayed, Unsure why its not displaying on my desktop.

[image]

Comment: In context your are passing `password_reset_form` and in the template you are using `form`.

Comment: @dgw The view is where the users submits the email to being the reset, the template is where the reset occurs, its a authview

Comment: @Wazy have u found any answer for your question. I am also facing the same issue